# changing a 3D list into a 2D list

Tags: python

I want to convert a 3D list (list_1) into a 2D list (list_2).
For example:

```
list_1: [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
list_2: [[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
[e for sl in lst for e in sl]
```

But the result would be different:

```
[[3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]
```

Comment: At this point, with two and three dimensions, using NumPy becomes very logical. `np.squeeze(list_1)` would do the trick here.

Answer (score 2):

For readibility I'd suggest [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to flatten the inner lists here:

```
from itertools import chain
l = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]

[list(chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in l]
# [[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

---

Following your approach, you'd need an extra level of looping to flatten the inner lists:

```
[[i for e in sl for i in e] for sl in l]
# [[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

another option:

```
[reduce(list.__add__, x)  for x in list_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this:

```
l = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]

print ([sum(item, []) for item in l])
```

output:

```
[[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close:

```
[[c for b in a for c in b] for a in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your nested lists contain single elements, you can use unpacking:

```
d = [[[3], [4]], [[5], [6]], [[7], [8]]]
new_d = [[i for [i] in b] for b in d]
```

Output:

```
[[3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```